# Geolocation with Google maps API and Google text Search

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am new to javascript converting from VB. This is my first shot at creating a dynamic google map and am ultimatly trying to generate a google map using the users location and apply a places search for sports stores. Currently my map generates and zooms to my location but does not apply the search results with markers.
here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>

    <article>
      <p>Finding your location: <span id="status">checking...</span></p>
    </article>
<script>
function success(position) {
  var s = document.querySelector('#status');
  
  if (s.className == 'success') {
    // not sure why we're hitting this twice in FF, I think it's to do with a cached result coming back    
    return;
  }
  
  s.innerHTML = "found you!";
  s.className = 'success';
  
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '560px';
    
  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);


  
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);
  var service;
  var infowindow;
 var request = {
    location: latlng,
    radius: '3200',
    query: 'sports'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.textSearch(request, callback);


function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
 }
}

function error(msg) {
  var s = document.querySelector('#status');
  s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
  s.className = 'fail';
  
  // console.log(arguments);
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}

</script>
```

I feel like I might be missing some var assignments or not over writing the current map from "map canvas". Has any one created something similar that provide some insight? Any help is greatly appreciated to find why my search results will not display on the map. Thanks!

Comment: What does the query response look like? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue in the question itself. Using the [posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/4vk6nco8/), I get "Finding your location: failed"

Comment: @geocodezip the response on I get can be found at [Code Example](http://www.cellphonerepairhq.com/local-repair/) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I get "Finding your location: failed" on that as well.  Can't debug the actual problem with your example.

Comment: @geocodezip It must be a setting on your browser, I just checked the current output in two states and it worked once location access was granted. Here is a link to a page I threw up to show the output as an image. [see current map](http://www.cellphonerepairhq.com/test/)

Comment: It is definitely a setting on my browser.  I deny geolocation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works but you are missing the `createMarker` function. This is not an API method.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createMarker is not defined
```

An example `createMarker` function:

```
function createMarker(place) {

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.geometry.location,
        map: map
    });
}
```

**Note**: if you only need the location in that function you could also call it and modify it this way:

```
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
            console.log(place);
            createMarker(results[i].geometry.location); // pass only the location to createMarker
        }
    }
}

function createMarker(position) {

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
    });
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3s90cvnu/)</kbd>

Comment: As soon as I am able I gladly will. My rep is at a 9 and needs to be at 15.